# Trying to prove noncompactness over the discrete metric

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, compactness

I wrote this version of proof. But would like some feedback. I am proving that the discrete metric $(X,d)$ is not compact. $X$ is infinite, it contains infinitely many points

> Let $x_i \in X$, then for $i \neq j$, $d(x_i, x_j) = 1$. So $x_i \in N_1(x_i) \implies x_i \in \cup_{i \geq 1} N_1(x_i) = Y$ for all $i$. Thus $X \subset Y$ and $Y$ is a cover for $X$. Suppose $Y$ has finite subcover $Y'$, by finiteness of $Y'$, there exists a largest integer $k$ s.t $x_k \in Y$; consider $x_{k+1}\in X$, since $Y'$ is a cover, then $x_{k+1} \in Y'$, but $\cap_{i \geq 1} N_1(x_i) = \emptyset$, a contradiction, so $Y'$ DNE.

**EDIT**: I am also trying to find a sequence proof. I can't think of sequence in this metric space that does not have convergent subsequence in $X$

Comment: A set $X$ is compact in the discrete topology when (in fact, if and only if) $X$ is finite. Are you assuming that $X$ is infinite?

Comment: But *it is compact*...if $\,|X|<\infty\,$ , say. I just can't understand your supposed proof.

Comment: Yes $X$ is infinite, it contains many points

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let’s take a detailed look at your argument:

> Let $x_i \in X$, then for $i \neq j$, $d(x_i, x_j) = 1$. So $x_i \in N_1(x_i) \implies x_i \cup_{i \geq 1} N_1(x_i) = Y$ for all $i$. Thus $X \subset Y$ and $Y$ is a cover for $X$. Suppose $Y$ has finite subcover $Y'$, by finiteness of $Y'$, there exists a largest integer $k$ s.t $x_k \in Y$; consider $x_{k+1}\in X$, since $Y'$ is a cover, then $x_{k+1} \in Y'$, but $\cap_{i \geq 1} N_1(x_i) = \emptyset$, a contradiction, so $Y'$ DNE.

You’re already in a little trouble with the first sentence, though it’s sloppiness more than a real problem:

> Let $x_i \in X$, then for $i \neq j$, $d(x_i, x_j) = 1$.

First, you’ve not told us over what set the index $i$ ranges. From later evidence it appears that you intend it to range over $\Bbb Z^+$, the set of positive integers; **say so**. You also haven’t explicitly stated a very important assumption that you’re making about the points $x_i$, namely, that if $i\ne j$, then $x_i\ne x_j$. There are many legitimate ways to say what you wanted to say here. Here are a couple:

- Let $\{x_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ be a set of distinct points in $X$; this is possible because by hypothesis $X$ is infinite. Then $d(x_i,x_j)=1$ for $i,j\in\Bbb Z^+$ with $i\ne j$.
- For each $i\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $x_i\in X$. Since $X$ is infinite, we may assume that $x_i\ne x_j$ and hence $d(x_i,x_j)=1$ whenever $i\ne j$.

Both of those are a little more detailed than would be necessary if you were further along, but at this stage you need to be very careful about saying exactly what you mean and making your various hypotheses explicit: if you force yourself to think about what you’re writing and to fill in all the blanks, you’ll catch more of your logical errors.

You’re in real trouble with the second sentence:

> So $x_i \in N_1(x_i) \implies x_i \cup_{i \geq 1} N_1(x_i) = Y$ for all $i$.

For starters, $x_i \cup_{i \geq 1} N_1(x_i)$ is not well-formed: $x_i$ is not a set, and $\cup_{i\ge 1}$ is not a binary operation. I suspect that you mean $\{x_i\}\cup\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N_1(x_i)$ or something similar, but this still doesn’t make much sense: in $\{x_i\}$ the subscript $i$ apparently refers to a particular point of $X$, while in $\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N(x_i)$ it’s a dummy variable ranging over the positive integers. Moreover, as I noted in discussing the first sentence, you haven’t really defined the $x_i$ in the first place. Worse, this is the first appearance of $Y$; what is it? If this is its definition, you need to tell us so; otherwise we look back to find out what it is and find ... nothing. We shouldn’t have to look ahead, but let’s see if the next sentence sheds any light on $Y$.

> Thus $X \subset Y$ and $Y$ is a cover for $X$.

Okay, it looks as if the previous sentence was supposed to be a definition of $Y$; my guess is that you want to define $Y=\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N_1(x_i)$, making $Y$ the union of the open $1$-balls centred at the points $x_i$. You should have said so instead of making the reader guess. But there’s a worse problem here: there’s no reason to think that $X$ is necessarily a subset of $Y$. Suppose, for instance, that $X=\Bbb R$, but with the discrete metric instead of the usual one; then $X$ is an uncountable set. $Y$, on the other hand, is only countable: $N_1(x_i)=\{x_i\}$ for each $i\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $Y=\{x_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. In this example $X\nsubseteq Y$.

Even when $X$ **is** a subset of $Y$, it is incorrect to say that $Y$ is a cover of $X$. The cover that you have in mind here is $\{N_1(x_i):i\ge 1\}$, the collection of open $1$-balls whose union is $Y$. Sn open cover of a set $X$ is a **collection** of open sets whose union contains $X$: it’s the collection of open sets, not their union.

At this point so much is wrong that it’s hard to proceed, but let’s assume that when you talk about $Y$, you’re really talking about $\{N_1(x_i):i\ge 1\}$ and that this actually is an open cover of $X$ (which really means that $X=\{x_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\}$). Let $\mathscr{U}=\{N_1(x_i):i\ge 1\}$.

> Suppose $Y$ has finite subcover $Y'$, by finiteness of $Y'$, there exists a largest integer $k$ s.t $x_k \in Y$;

From what I’ve already said you should be able to correct this to:

> Suppose that $\mathscr{U}$ has a finite subcover $\mathscr{U}'$. Since $\mathscr{U}'$ is finite, there is a largest integer $k$ such that $N_1(x_k)\in\mathscr{U}'$.

Now for the rest:

> consider $x_{k+1}\in X$, since $Y'$ is a cover, then $x_{k+1} \in Y'$, but $\cap_{i \geq 1} N_1(x_i) = \emptyset$, a contradiction, so $Y'$ DNE.

The actual subcover is $\mathscr{U}'$, and $x_{k+1}$ isn’t even the right kind of object to be a member of it: its members are open $1$-balls, not points. Since $\mathscr{U}'$ is finite, we can enumerate it as $$\mathscr{U}'=\{N_1(x_{i_1}),N_1(x_{i_2}),\dots,N_1(x_{i_m})\}$$ for some positive integers $i_1,\dots,i_m$. (And if $i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_m$, then $i_m=k$; why?) I think that what you were trying to say is that since $\mathscr{U}'$ covers $X$, its union must contain the point $x_{k+1}$:

$$x_{k+1}\in N_1(x_{i_1})\cup N_1(x_{i_2})\cup\dots\cup N_1(x_{i_m})\;.$$

There is a contradiction to be had at this point, but it’s not the one that you wrote: it’s true that the sets $N_1(x_i)$ have empty intersection, but that by itself is a non sequitur. The contradiction comes from the fact that

$$N_1(x_{i_1})\cup N_1(x_{i_2})\cup\dots\cup N_1(x_{i_m})=\{x_{i_1},x_{i_2},\dots,x_{i_m}\}\;,$$

where $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_m\le k$, and therefore $x_{k+1}\notin\{x_{i_1},x_{i_2},\dots,x_{i_m}\}$.

---

As julien pointed out in his answer, you’re working much too hard even where you **are** on the right track. Here’s all you have to say:

> Suppose that $X$ is compact, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{N_1(x):x\in X\}$; clearly $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$. If $X$ is compact, $\mathscr{U}$ has a finite subcover $\{N_1(x_1),N_1(x_2),\dots,N_1(x_n)\}$ for some positive integer $n$ and points $x_1,\dots,x_n\in X$. But for each $x\in X$ we have $N_1(x)=\{x\}$, so $$X=N_1(x_1)\cup N_1(x_2)\cup\ldots\cup N_1(x_n)=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}\;,$$ i.e., $X$ is finite. Taking the contrapositive, we see that if $X$ is infinite, it cannot be compact.

---

You mentioned wanting to make an argument using sequences. Let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ be any sequence of distinct points of $X$, i.e., such that $x_m\ne x_n$ whenever $m\ne n$; then $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ does not converge to any point of $X$. To see this, let $x\in X$. Then $N_1(x)=\{x\}$.

- If $x\notin\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$, then $N_1(x)$ is an open nbhd of $x$ that contains no term of the sequence, so the sequence certainly doesn’t converge to $x$.
- If $x=x_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then for all $k>n$ we have $x\ne x_k$ and hence $x_k\notin N_1(x)$. Thus, $N_1(x)$ is an open nbhd of $x$ that does not contain any tail of the sequence, which therefore cannot converge to $x$.

Now observe that if $X$ is infinite, we can certainly choose a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ of distinct points of $X$. This sequence cannot have a convergent subsequence, because every subsequence of it is **also** a sequence of distinct points and therefore does not converge.

Comment: @sizz: No, $$\left\{\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N_1(x_i)\right\}$$ is the set whose only member is the union, and you want the union itself. The version in your first comment is almost right, but $x_i\in\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N_1(x_i)$ still has the problem that you’re using $i$ for two different things. In the first $x_i$ it’s a particular value of $i$; in the union it’s a dummy variable. You need to change the name of the dummy variable: $x_i\in\bigcup_{j\ge 1}N_1(x_j)$ would do, for instance.

Comment: The set $$\left\{\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N_1(x_i)\right\}$$ is a collection of (one) union open sets. No?  Why do you say the disjoint open sets is non sequitur? . Also at some point you write that the nbhd $N_1(x) = \{ x\}$ What does this mean? You are saying the nbhd is equal to the set of one $x$?

Comment: @sizz: (1) The only element of $\left\{\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N_1(x_i)\right\}$ is $\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N_1(x_i)$, which is not one of the points $x_i$. The points $x_i$ are elements of $\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N_1(x_i)$, not of the set whose only element is $\bigcup_{i\ge 1}N_1(x_i)$. (2) Because it does nothing to justify the conclusion that you want to draw. (3) Exactly. That’s the key to the whole business! $N_1(x)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<1\}=\{x\}$. The only point of $X$ whose distance from $x$ is less than $1$ is $x$ itself.

Comment: (1) But that's what I want, I want the single element of set to be the union of all the neighborhoods, this is my cover.

Comment: Also maybe it isn't too important (or I am wrong), but you wrote $$N_1(x_{i_1})\cup N_1(x_{i_2})\cup\dots\cup N_1(x_{i_m})=\{x_{i_1},x_{i_2},\dots,x_{i_m}\}\;,$$, do you actually mean that $$\{N_1(x_{i_1}),N_1(x_{i_2}),\dots,N_1(x_{i_m})\} =\{x_{i_1},x_{i_2},\dots,x_{i_m}\}\;,$$

Comment: @sizz: I meant exactly what I wrote; your version is simply wrong. $$\{N_1(x_{i_1}),N_1(x_{i_2}),\dots,N_1(x_{i_m})\}=\big\{\{x_{i_1}\{,\{x_{i_2}\},\dots,\{x_{i_m}\}\big\}$, not $\{x_{i_1},x_{i_2},\dots,x_{i_m}\}$. And going back to the previous comment, no, you **don’t** want the single element to be the union of the nbhds: that is not your cover. Your cover is the set whose elements are the nbhds. It is not the union of the nbhds, and it is not the set whose only element is the union of the nbhds.

Comment: I think I am seeing my problem here (and maybe yours too, with mine). The nbhds are sets themselves, what I wrote is putting a set inside another set equaling to an element, which makes no sense. So what you had was a set containing open sets which form a cover. (2) I am also puzzled by * It is not the union of the nbhds, and it is not the set whose only element is the union of the nbhds.* So what does the union of nbhd cover? Nothing?

Comment: @sizz: The union of the sets forming a cover is the whole space $X$. But the union of the sets forming the cover is not the same thing as the cover itself. The former is one subset of the space, namely $X$ itself; the latter is a collection of subsets of the space. $\mathscr{U}=\{(n,n+2):n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is an open cover of $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology; it’s a collection of open intervals. Since it’s a cover of $\Bbb R$, the union of all these intervals is $\Bbb R$, but $\mathscr{U}$, $\Bbb R$, and $\{\Bbb R\}$ are three completely different things.

Comment: @sizz: An open cover of $X$ is by definition a set whose members are open subsets of $X$; it has in addition the property that the union of these open sets is $X$.

Comment: *But the union of the sets forming the cover is not the same thing as the cover itself*, so you are telling me that for some metric space $X$, $X$ itself can't be an cover for itself? This is what I am understanding from what you said and the example you gave.

Comment: @sizz: No $X$ is not an open cover of $X$. How can it be? It’s not even a set of open subsets of $X$. $\{X\}$ is an open cover of $X$. These are not the same thing, and I’m pretty sure that you’re having difficulty keeping them straight. In any case, $\{X\}$ is not the open cover that we were talking about in the proof of the theorem, however, or the open cover $\mathscr{U}$ in my last comment but one.

Comment: (1) I am hvaing trouble understanding your sequential proof. If I take say $(1,0,1,0,1...),$ doesn't it have a convergent subsequence of $(0,0,0,0,0...) \to 0$? (2) I will edit and show you a proof of mine later

Comment: @sizz: Yes, that sequence has a convergent subsequence. But that sequence is irrelevant to the argument that I gave: it is not a sequence of distinct points.

Comment: Okay so something like $(1,1/2, 1/3, 1/4....)$? Because $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,x) \neq 0$? In fact the limit is $1$. That's what you were saying right? Also please see my edit proof thank

Comment: @sizz: Yes, in the sense that the points are distinct, but remember, $X$ is any old set, so its elements need not be real numbers at all. There are some real problems with the new proof, but both my answer and this string of comments are so long that it would be better if you posted it as a new question asking for feedback specifically on it.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $X$ is infinite.

You have the open cover
$$
X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}.
$$
If $X$ is compact, you can extract a finite subcover, say
$$
X\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^k\{x_i\}.
$$
(Of course, this is actually an equality, but it does not matter for this argument)

Then $X$ has at most $k$ (actually exactly $k$) elements, a contradiciton.

So $X$ infinite implies $X$ not compact.

Of course, the converse is true.

Comment: @sizz That's the other way around. By contradiction, if $X$ is compact, you can, so $X$ is finite. Since you assume $X$ is infinite, this shows that $X$ is not compact.

Comment: I don't know what you did because I don't know what $N_1(x)$ is.

Comment: @sizz But that's actually much easier than your argument. I have completed the argument.

Comment: @sizz Because the other inclusion is trivial since everything lies in $X$.

Comment: @sizz Well this is trivial too. A set is equal to the union of its elements. Sorry, but your proof makes a trivial fact way too complicated. And noite that an arbitrary sequence is not necessarily injective, which is what you seem to assume. Finally, to make a sequence proof here you do not need to consider covers.

Comment: So you were saying that the set of discrete points (union all) is a cover? But do discrete points form an open set? Okay I think I see what you did now. So here in my proof I took a nontrivial cover (you took the trivial one, that is itself) and basically wrote a few extra lines of what you did. No I know that I don't need to consider covers for sequences proof. I am saying I am trying to come up with one. I want to do both

Comment: @sizz I think this will be my last comment, since there are already way too many. Yes $\{x\}$ is the open ball of radius $1/2$ centered at $x$, so it is open.

Comment: You never stated that $\{ x \}$has a radius though...

Comment: @sizz Ok, this is the last. No. I am just saying it turns out that the open ball $\{y\in X\;;\;d(x,y)<1/2\}$ boils down to the singleton $\{x\}$ in this context.